# While calling a no parameterized function wants a parameter swift

Tags: swift, parameters

I wrote that function using Duncan C's post. I entered not parameter but while calling function Xcode wants a ViewController parameter. How can I solve that issue?

Edit: I added rest of the code. What's destroying the assign() function?

calling:
[image: calling]

```
        import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {




    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        firstInput.returnKeyType = .Search
        firstInput.delegate = self
        textBox.text = ""


    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       if firstInput.text == "" {
       }
       else {
          getFromPath()

       }
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }


    func search(#set: [String], letters: String) -> [String] {

        let result = filter(set) { item in
            for char in letters {
                if !contains(item, char) {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        }

        return result
    }

    func assign(){

        let path = "/Users/ardakaraca/Documents/Xcode/ATC Radio/Stands/Stands/words.txt"
        //let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        //let path = bundle.pathForResource("words", ofType: "txt")
        let content = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        let newArray = content!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")




        }
         let newConten



    func getFromPath() {
        //getFromPath() func used to be in assign func.
        var letters = firstInput.text
        var res = search(set: newArray, letters: letters)
        textBox.text! = ""
        for element in res {
            textBox.text = (textBox.text ?? "") + "\n" + "\(element)"
        }

}

}
```

Comment: You need to provide some more context.  If I copy this method into a playground and then type `let dictArray = assign()` it works perfectly fine (sort of... it certainly doesn't have this problem).

Comment: I edited the question and added the rest of the code.

Comment: You are coding for iOS and trying to use a path to your documents folder at your Mac ?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus.. It's reasonable while testing on a Simulator..

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus As you see in comment in assign() func, I wrote and commented. While distributing I'll use them. It's for simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined `assign()` as an *instance method* of the `ViewController()` class, which means that it must be called on an
instance of that class.

If you try to initialize a property of that class with

```
let dictArray = assign()
```

then `assign` is taken as a "curried function" of the type

```
ViewController -> () -> [String]
```

which explains the unexpected autocompletion in Xcode (see
http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/).

The easiest
solution would be to move the `assign()` function out of the
`ViewController` class and define it as a "free function"
(and perhaps choose a better name for that function):

```
import UIKit

func getWordList() -> [String] {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("words", ofType: "txt")!
    let content = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    let wordList = content!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    return wordList
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let wordList = getWordList()

    // ...
}
```